# Accessing Python Dictionary mappings from JSON load()

Tags: python, json, object, properties

I am using JSON to parse an object to a Python object.  I have an array that looks like this:

```
arr=['a','b','c']
```

and the JSON data looks like this:

```
{"a":"hhh","b":1,"c":"nnnn"}
```

I load the data using json.load() method into an object called 'item'.  If I attempt to get the value for b using this syntax:

```
print(item["b"])
```

The result is:

```
1
```

However, if I loop through the array and use the value in the array to print the property of the object, the program fails on trying to get 'b'.  Here is the code I am using and the result:

```
for i in arr:
    try:
        print(item[i])
    except:
        print(i + ": Failed!")
```

The result is:

```
hhh
b: Failed!
nnnn
```

I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Use `json.loads()` instead `load()`. It will help

Comment: try `print(str(item[i]))`

Comment: bulbus - that was it!  Thanks.